# Can I initialize a InitialSessionSpace from a session configuration file?

Tags: powershell

I host a Powershell runspace in c#, but would like the session configuration file mechanism to configure my runspace. Is it possible to use session configuration files from your c# code, without interpreting the file from custom code? Session configuration files are described at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847838.aspx